# Prevent browser form submission when Wicket AjaxFormValidatingBehaviour validation fails

Tags: java, wicket

I have a Page with a Wizard component. The user can navigate the panels of the wizard by using the *next* and *previous* buttons which I have performing full (non-ajax) form submissions so that the app is back-button friendly.

When the *next* button is clicked, I would like to attempt ajax form validation (if javascript is enabled). I tried doing:

```
nextButton.add( new AjaxFormValidatingBehavior( form, "onsubmit") );
```

to add such validation. The behaviour works - however, when validation errors occur the browser still submits the entire form.

What is the Wicket way to prevent the browser from submitting the form in this case?

Comment: Can't you use the isComplete() method in your WizardStep? That method, I think, should return true if your step is valid or not. That should enable/disable the buttons properly.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onError()` method on either the form or the `AjaxFormValidatingBehavior`. If you do it on the behavior, I am not sure if that will prevent the form from submitting or not.

```
new AjaxFormValidatingBehavior( form, "onsubmit") {
   public void onSubmit() {}
   public void onError() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what could I put in onError() to stop the submission though? It appears that on the client side there is no script preventing the full form submission from happening. I'm not sure how I could prevent that from happening unless there are no validation errors. I've tried implementing getFailureScript by returning "return false;" to attempt to squash the event, but to no avail.

Comment: Add a `FeedbackPanel` to the top of your form. Then in `onError()` you add it to the target so it gets refreshed through Ajax (`target.addComponent(feedbackPanel)`). If there are validation errors, the FeedbackPanel should show the corresponding error messages. You can also add custom messages to the panel (`feedbackPanel.error("Validation Error")`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit to late but here is the answer:

```
public class SomePage extends WebPage {

    private FeedbackPanel feedbackMessageError = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackTabAddEmpMesError", new ExactLevelFeedbackMessageFilter(FeedbackMessage.ERROR));

    public SomePage(String id) {

      final Form<Void> form = new Form<>("tabFormAddEmp");
      add(form);

      //Name textfield cannot be empty
      final FormComponent<String> tabAddEmpName = new RequiredTextField<>("tabAddEmpName", Model.of(""));
      tabAddEmpName.setLabel(Model.of("Name"));
      tabAddEmpName.setOutputMarkupId(true);

      //Salarynumber has to be minimal 10 char long
      final FormComponent<String> tabAddEmpLoon = new RequiredTextField<>("tabAddEmpLoon", Model.of(""));
      tabAddEmpLoon.add(new StringValidator(10, null)).setLabel(Model.of("Salarynumber"));
      tabAddEmpLoon.setOutputMarkupId(true);

      final Button button = new Button("tabFormAddEmpBut");

      form.add(tabAddEmpName , tabAddEmpLoon, button);

      button.add(new AjaxFormValidatingBehavior(form, "onclick") {

        @Override
        public void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
             //Add feedbackpanel to your html and voila!
             target.add(feedbackMessageError);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
          //Do some logic over here
        }

      }

   }
}
```